# Type-hinting problem with mypy when iterating through a list of arguments

Tags: python, mypy

Here is a MRE:

```py
def test(a: int | tuple[int, int]):
    print(a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for b in [1, (1, 2)]:
        test(b)
```

mypy outputs:
`7: error: Argument 1 to "test" has incompatible type "object"; expected "Union[int, Tuple[int, int]]"  [arg-type]`

But I'm passing to the function `func` an `integer` and a `tuple` of `two integers`, hence why I don't understand the error.

I'm using:

```
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
plugins: anyio-3.6.2, mypy-0.10.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mypy is inferring the type of `[1, (1, 2)]` as `list[object]` (since that's the common denominator of the types in the list); it doesn't automatically infer union types.

The best solution I can think of is to explicitly declare the type of the list by giving it a name and annotation:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a: list[int | tuple[int, int]] = [1, (1, 2)]
    for b in a:
        test(b)
```

but I would suggest examining the real-world context where you're hitting this situation and see if you can avoid having a list of mixed types in the first place (this is IMO a smell that the data isn't organized in the most effective way).

Comment: My function basically behaves differently if I input a `tuple` or an `integer`. In my function there is an `isinstance` to differentiate the two behaviours. Would that be bad practice? I didn't want to make two different functions that achieved the same goal which is why I went for this approach. I know that in Java people tend to do that (several functions with the same name but not the same input types).

Comment: I typically have multiple functions with different names when different types of input are expected (refactor as needed to avoid code duplication).  If the `isinstance` is doing something like, say, converting the single int into a tuple with a default value, maybe it'd be better to just have it take the tuple and do the normalization outside the function?

Comment: Well the function just completely behaves differently when it's an integer. It achieves the same goal though.

Comment: I might be better off creating two functions in that case.

Comment: If it does a completely different thing, it should be a completely different function.